# Symfony2 Change class name in twig form theme

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to override `form_widget_simple` function

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {{dump(form.vars.attr)}}
    {% endif %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

but I dont know how to set `form.vars.attr['class']` inside `if` statement
Whent I do `set form.vars.attr['class'] = 'error';` I get error `Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected)`

Comment: Do you want to add a fix `class` (for css-classes) attribute to the `<input>` element?

Comment: Yes, add another `class` to existing one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you see, adding additional attributes is handled in the `widget_attributes` block. If you take a look in there, you see a [simple foreach over the `attr` array](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L309), with all the attributes. I think a simple set with merging existing one, could be done. So your `form_widget_simple` block will look like

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {{dump(form.vars.attr)}}
    {% endif %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' your-css-class')|trim}) %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

This will preserve every class attribute set in the form builder and add `your-css-class` as additional class. If no class attribute is defined, only `your-css-class` is set.